# How can i get unban account

Tags: support, post-ban, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

How can i get unban Stackoverglow account.

Yes I wrote a question, then I removed them. But my English is poor and after addition of the questions I found that I can not explain this about what I wanted to ask.

Can you do this for me ?

Comment: Basic summary: No, we can't do anything for you. You should improve your current contributions as much as possible. And subsequently positively contribute in ways the site still allows and gain rep in doing so. Then you might be automatically unbanned again at a certain point.

Comment: First tip: proof-read what you post. Even when your English is poor, you certainly know that the name of this site is not Stackoverglow.

Comment: Right, as @Bart says, poor English shouldn't be used as an excuse for blatant typos. Just do your best and put forth effort; the community will happily meet you half-way. Good luck!

Comment: Here's a hint: in the message that you got when you tried to ask a question, there's a link. Click on the link. Read the page to which the link points. And then ask yourself **why you didn't bother to do that before opening a question on meta**!

Comment: I think I prefer Stack Overglow - makes it all sparkly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undelete the questions. Deleting questions indicates that the material you posted isn't right for Stack Overflow, and it doesn't matter whether you deleted it or the community deleted it. The results are still the same.

Instead, undelete the questions. If there are problems with them, edit them to try to clean them up. Leaving questions undeleted also gives other community members an opportunity to help you clean up your questions.

However, if they're deleted, no one can help you fix them, and they sit there contributing to the question ban. Start there, and see if that helps. Good luck!

Note: If undeleting them doesn't help, see Michael Petrotta's link: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) The only person who can really undo the ban is you.

**If you can't see your own deleted content, I'd suggest flagging one of your posts for diamond moderator attention and asking a mod to undelete the questions you deleted so you can edit them and fix them.**

Comment: Don't forget that < 10k users can't see their own deleted questions.

Comment: Really, I thought we could always see our own deleted content. In that case, one of the diamonds would have to come in and undelete the deleted questions. Kubus, I'd suggest flagging one of your posts for diamond moderator attention and asking a mod to undelete the questions you deleted so you can edit them and fix them.